# regex build error on win7 64bit

Tags: c++, regex, windows, visual-studio, build

I got this two build error on VS2008 and Windows 7 64bit:

1. `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::tr1::_Xbad(enum std::tr1::regex_constants::error_type)" (__imp_?_Xbad@tr1@std@@YAXW4error_type@regex_constants@12@@Z) referenced in function "public: static unsigned __int64 __cdecl std::tr1::_Regex_traits<char>::length(char const *)" (?length@?$_Regex_traits@D@tr1@std@@SA_KPEBD@Z)`
2. `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::tr1::_Xmem(void)" (__imp_?_Xmem@tr1@std@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl std::tr1::_Buf<char>::_Expand(int)" (?_Expand@?$_Buf@D@tr1@std@@AEAAXH@Z)`

Does that ring any bell? The code was fine on VS2008 and Windows 7 32 bit, but did not build on a 64 bit machine. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not fully sure but I would think your code is looking for some x64 libraries for it to compile. For the fact that it works on 32bit, its likely your code contains 32bit object codes.

Comment: Seems VC features 2008 pack solves the problem, not sure why though. Thanks.

Comment: Good to see that you have solved it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded VC feature 2008, and the problem is gone after installation. I did this because I saw another poster said so somewhere online.

Here it is:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6922